# How to use the ArrayHelper::multisort() in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a question.

In Yii2

> public static void multisort ( &$array, $key, $direction = SORT_ASC,
>   $sortFlag = SORT_REGULAR )

The document say $key can be a function,but i set a function as the $key,the result not change.

how to use the $key as function.

my code is

```
$arr = [
        0=>['id'=>1,'name'=>'abei'],
        1=>['id'=>4,'name'=>'li'],
        3=>['id'=>4,'name'=>'wb'],
        4=>['id'=>3,'name'=>'world']
    ];  


    ArrayHelper::multisort($arr,function($item){
        return isset($item['id']) ? ['id', 'name'] : 'name';
    },SORT_DESC);
    var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an &  before $item    try remove it

```
ArrayHelper::multisort($arr,function($item){
    return isset($item['id']) ? ['id', 'name'] : 'name';
},SORT_DESC);
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: I remove &,The result not change

Comment: your id is always setted .. what's your expected  result and your actual result

Comment: I only study the document.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html#multidimensional-sorting

Comment: What do you mean  .. the multisorf clousere have a signature  function($var)   .. the this var is used (as $item)  inside the function body ... if you need  others vars  you can pass them to the clusure  using function($var) use ($myVar)   and the youcan use $var as $item and $myVra inside the body ... hope is clear otherwise take a look at clousure signature